# Windows equivalent to Linux `cat -n`?

Tags: command-line, window

In Linux, I can easily view any files with line number next to it with `cat -n` command.

```
sh-4.4$ cat test   
line 1             
line 2             
line 3             
sh-4.4$ 

sh-4.4$ cat test -n
     1  line 1     
     2  line 2     
     3  line 3     
sh-4.4$
```

What about Windows? Is there any similar command producing similar output?

`type` is one of the windows command to view content of the file.

```
C:\>type test.txt
line 1
line 2
line 3
C:\>
```

However, there is no `-n` option in it.

```
C:\>type /?
Displays the contents of a text file or files.

TYPE [drive:][path]filename

C:\>
```

This is what I'm expecting in Windows

```
C:\>(windows command to view and print line number) test.txt
     1  line 1     
     2  line 2     
     3  line 3     
C:\>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without installing a 3rd party tools, this can be done using Powershell, but there is a little bit of scripting complexity as seen below.  What is nice about this script is that it will work with any DOS command that produces output.

> $i = 1; cat food.txt | % {$i++;"$($i-1) `t $_"}

**Note**: Powershell has the `cat` command, as seen in the script, but it lacks line numbering.  It is an alias for the PowerShell command `get-content`.

Here is the output:

```
1        Apples
2        Bananas
3        Carrots
```

Here is an example with a directory listing by simply executing `dir` in the script:

> $i = 1; dir | % {$i++;"$($i-1) `t $_"}

Here is the output:

```
1        backgrounds
2        boot
3        inetpub
4        PerfLogs
5        Program Files
6        Program Files (x86)
7        Riot Games
8        Users
9        Windows
10       Reflect_Install.log
```

If you want line numbering to start at 0, then set $i = 0

---

Alternatively, you can install 3rd party `cat` program in Windows.  There are many ports of UNIX commands to Windows, such as [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) and [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).

After installing Cygwin's base install:

> C:\cygwin64\bin\cat -n food.txt

Outputs:

```
 1  apple
 2  banana
 3  bread
 4  cake
```

Comment: It works very well with Powershell.

`PS C:\> $i = 1; cat .\test.txt | % {$i++;"$($i-1) `t $_"}
1        line 1
2        line 2
3        line 3
PS C:\>
PS C:\> $i = 1; get-content .\test.txt | % {$i++;"$($i-1) `t $_"}
1        line 1
2        line 2
3        line 3
PS C:\>`

Comment: @Sabrina Glad it helped.  Although, simply installing a 'cat' program might be more convenient in the long run

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Windows equivalent of cat -n

```
findstr /n . "C:\Temp\myfile.txt"
```

The `/n` shows line numbers. The `.` is a regular expression that matches even a blank line.

To more clearly call out to readers what that command really does:

```
findstr.exe /n /r ".*"
```

Comment: `.` matches a line containing one or more space(s), but not an empty line, which is what is most commonly used for a 'blank' line; as a result the numbers aren't consecutive